# Lex and Yacc and EBNF specification

Tags: yacc, lex

if I just want to check whether the syntax of a language is correct or not,
what is the easy way of writing a syntax analyzer using yacc.

Comment: Your 'EBNF' is not much like the EBNF defined by ISO 14977:1996.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the ISO standard for EBNF is ISO 14977:1996 and the 'EBNF' you've used in the question bears limited resemblance to the standard version.  That leaves us having to interpret your grammar rule.

- Non-terminals are written as single words in all lower-case.
- Terminals are written as single words in all upper-case.
- Colon is used to separate a non-terminal from its definition.
- Dot (period) is used to mark the end of a rule.
- Square brackets enclose optional (zero or once) material.

With those definitions in mind, you need:

- A lexical analyzer that recognizes DECLARATION, OF, CONST, VAR, END as terminals (keywords).
- A grammar that contains rules for declaration_unit, ident, const_declaration, var_declaration, procedure_interface, function_interface.

Given:

```
%token DECLARATION
%token OF
%token CONST
%token VAR
%token END

%%

declaration_unit
    :   DECLARATION OF ident opt_const_declaration opt_var_declaration
        opt_procedure_interface opt_function_interface DECLARATION END
    ;

opt_const_declaration
    :   /* Nothing */
    |   CONST const_declaration
    ;

opt_var_declaration
    :   /* Nothing */
    |   VAR var_declaration
    ;

opt_procedure_interface
    :   /* Nothing */
    |   procedure_interface
    ;

opt_function_interface
    :   /* Nothing */
    |   function_interface
    ;
```

You now just have to fill in the rules for `ident`, `const_declaration`, `var_declaration`, `procedure_interface`, `function_interface`.

For simple syntax checking, you could add placeholder tokens and rules for the parts of the grammar that you've not yet fully defined.  For example, you might add:

```
%token IDENT
%token CONST_DECLARATION
%token VAR_DECLARATION
%token PROCEDURE_INTERFACE
%token FUNCTION_INTERFACE
```

and

```
ident
    :   IDENT
    ;

const_declaration
    :   CONST_DECLARATION
    ;

var_declaration
    :   VAR_DECLARATION
    ;

procedure_interface
    :   PROCEDURE_INTERFACE
    ;

function_interface
    :   FUNCTION_INTERFACE
    ;
```

Your lexical analyzer simply needs to be able to recognize those dummy tokens reliably until you provide the correct rules.