# How to parsing a text file for function signatures regardless of the line breaks

Tags: parsing, text, text-parsing

I'm new to text parsing domain. My question is about methodology of text file parsing for a given function signature to evaluate coding errors. There is no decision which language to use parse the text file. Here is a brief description of the situation.

1. There is a text file containing user written functions (say c++ as the language, and only evaluate user defined function. i.e. non-native).
2. It could contain both single and multi-line comments delimited by // and /* */ respectively.
3. Commented lines should not be evaluated for coding errors. Empty lines also skipped.
4. Functions to be evaluated already maintained in a list along with it's parameters. Parameters have to be called with allowable values only. Therefore each parameter value should be validated in the function.
5. These are the complications in the evaluation.

   - Function can be span multiple lines.
   - In a function call there may be another functions call for a given parameter position. If this is also user defined and is in the given list, should be evaluated as well.
   - After evaluation, generate a report to indicate the incorrect function calls with following information.

> Line Number,
>   Function Name,
>   Invalid argument position

Here is a sample. (CRLF indicates line endings)

```
f1(f1_arg1, f1_arg2, f2(f2_arg1, f2_arg2), f1_arg3) <CRLF>

f1(f1_arg1, f1_arg2, f2(f2_arg1, <CRLF>
f2_arg2), f1_arg3) <CRLF>

f1(f1_arg1, f2(f2_arg1, f2_arg2), <CRLF>
 f3(f3_arg1)) <CRLF>

f1(f1_arg1 <CRLF>
, f2(f2_arg1, f2_arg2), <CRLF>
f3(f3_arg1)) <CRLF>

f1( <CRLF>
f1_arg1, f2(f2_arg1, f2_arg2), <CRLF>
 f3(f3_arg1)) <CRLF>
```

I think this can not be parse as a stream since I have to consider whether the current line is commented.

What is the best way to evaluate functions regardless of its span in multiple line?

Thanks,
Indika.

Comment: If you use a counter for the "(" and then a counter for the ")" you can keep track of where that function ends more easily.  Not sure if it will help with the whole problem though.

Comment: Generally I think evaluation method should be recursive since an argument can have another user defined function call. Then if it is spanning multiple lines, current line should be advanced to read rest of the parameters from next line as shown in examples.

Comment: Define your EBNF, then use YACC. See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/26133516/2908724.